# Flex box fit width with it's childs when child is out of window?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using a `column wrap` layout, and the page is going to load new content and append them as new children elements to the parent box element, so I hope the box width `auto fit` to the children elements.

Codes here: https://codepen.io/mashirozx/pen/exgRqV

What it looks now:
[image]

My hope (Notice the overflow-x bar):
[image]

---

Problem solved:

Adding `overflow: auto` to the flex box.

Comment: it works perfectly what browser do you use?

Comment: all you have to do is remove the width from child div.

Comment: i get the OP point:remove the `width:200%` from parent and you will see the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7h2o5mrp/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
flex-container-content > div {
  background-color: #EB213C;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;`
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the OP wants the scroll

Comment: ok in that case if he want scroll he have to add 'owerflow:scroll' in '.flex-container-content'  at your suggest  'width:200%'